# How to resolve hostnames in chroot?

Tags: chroot

I try to repair an broken Ubunu 14.04 with chroot. What I did, is to boot Ubuntu from USB mounted the original system that has to be repaired and changed to this system with chroot:

```
sudo mount /dev/sdXY /mnt 
sudo mount -o bind /dev /mnt/dev 
sudo mount -o bind /sys /mnt/sys 
sudo mount -t proc /proc /mnt/proc 
sudo cp /proc/mounts /mnt/etc/mtab 
sudo chroot /mnt /bin/bash
```

That worked fine, but in `chroot` environment I don't have access to the internet, so `apt` isn't able to resolve hostnames.
What am I supposed to do?

```
ping www.askubuntu.com
```

does not work either.

Comment: I think my command should be `for d in dev sys run proc; do sudo mount -o bind /$d /mnt/$d ; done`

Comment: try and get back to me soon :-)

Comment: Seems to work, but I am not quite sure, because it my be an other reason making it work. Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 36, accepted):

On newer Ubuntu systems, name resolution is handled by the resolvconf service, and /etc/resolv.conf is a symbolic link to /run/resolvconf/resolv.conf. You can either add a bind mount to the /run filesystem along with your other bind mounts before executing the chroot command

```
sudo mount -o bind /run /mnt/run
```

so that the chroot system picks up the host system's DNS settings or, once you're in the chrooted system, temporarily create a static /etc/resolv.conf with nameserver(s) of your choice e.g.

```
echo 'nameserver 8.8.4.4' | sudo tee -a /etc/resolv.conf
```

Comment: What are "newer Ubuntu systems"; in other words since which version is name resolution handled by resolvconf?

Comment: @ProBackup at least from 12.04 I think, although it may have been backported - see [DNS in Ubuntu 12.04](https://www.stgraber.org/2012/02/24/dns-in-ubuntu-12-04/)

Comment: doing `sudo mount --bind /run /mnt/run` worked for me chrooting into a botched 17.10 upgrade. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Is there a permanent solution?

Comment: It’s probably a bit defeating the purpose of chroot if you bind the whole /run directory with a lot of sockets, so probably binding only the needed sockets is a better idea (resolvconf, maybe nscd and syslog)

Comment: on 18.04 it's apparently enough to just copy /etc/resolv.conf to jail/etc/resolv.conf  (as an added security measure, i made sure it was owned by root and chmod'ed to 0444, but idk if that's important or not)

Comment: @eckes it depends what "the purpose" is imho - in this case, the chroot is being used for system recovery rather than as a jail

Comment: Yes agreed @steeldriver

Comment: this does not work if the host is using systemd. At least it does not work on ClearLinux circa 2020

Comment: Works fine on ubuntu 20.04 as host and finnix 122 as squashfs chrooted.