# Recommended way to install regular(cli) .deb packages on Ubuntu Phone?

Tags: ubuntu-touch

**tl;dr: I'm looking for a "canonical" or "recommended" way to install (cli) .deb packages on Ubuntu touch**

I've been using Ubuntu on my Desktop and Server for a year and I'm very satisfied. Now I bought the first Ubuntu phone, the BQ Aquaris e4.5 Ubuntu Edition. However, I found out that I can't install normal `.deb` packages or install things using `apt-get`. How can I "root" my phone so that I can install "normal" `.deb` packages?

I tried it myself. I know the first thing is to make your filesystem writable. I did the following steps but then I got stuck because of a dpkg error.

```
# Desktop:
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:phablet-team/tools
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install phablet-tools

# Phone:
Security & Privacy: Lock phone: Lock when idle: Never
About this phone: Developer Mode: Developer Mode ON

# connect phone to PC via USB

# Desktop:
adb devices
# no device detected so I've manually added file
touch /home/username/.android/adb_usb.ini
# with content: 0x2a47
sudo adb kill-server
sudo adb start-server
adb devices # now my phone is on the list

# Phone:
sudo test -w filename && echo "Writable" || echo "Not Writable"
# verified it is writable
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:phablet-team/ppa
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

And this is the place where error starts to block me:

```
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/powerd_0.16+15.04.20150430-0ubuntu1_armhf.deb (--unpack):
unable to make backup link of `./usr/share/powerd/device_configs/config-default.xml' before installing new version: Invalid cross-device link
```

So I tried

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

But it got stuck on "Bluetooth main config". I restarted the phone, but it didn't want to turn on anymore. I tried the `Recover` boot option. That worked.
I tried `install -f` again, and this time it worked. But after doing `upgrade` I still had the same error.

Comment: Making the system partition writable and using apt is not supported. If you really need to use some console apps for some reason, it is best to create a chroot inside the home directory, and then install what you need inside that chroot.

Comment: @dobey I totally understand it might be not supported and agree on that.
According to info in other SO questions by the co-developer of the [OS branch](bq/aquaris-E4.5) it should work.

Comment: That person is wrong. Using apt-get upgrade _will_ eventually result in a broken system on the phone images. If you want to use the phone as a server or something, then you should perhaps create a chroot to install and run services in. The phone as it is, is in fact Ubuntu. Just because it does not use/support apt, does not make it not Ubuntu.

Comment: @dobey Ubuntu is for me a brand that is backed by some scope of possibilities, and it that case it is not about the brand but the possibilities.

Comment: I can confirm that using apt-get upgrade will result in a broken system. Been there, done that.

Comment: BTW: I really don't get what you are trying to do. Are you trying to remount the root as writable? You can do this very easily from the device itself. Are you trying to install regular ubuntu packages? You'll need to change the repo's. The phone is on its own repo for the moment.

Comment: @Galgalesh I would like to be able to run any deb packages which I can run on cli ubuntu server - of course limited to those compiled for arm.  If *remounting* can be done once, and it will allows to enjoy Ubuntu, then it sounds like an answer to my question!

Comment: @Galgalesh thanks for the edit, not looks much better. As for now your answer is going to grab a bounty :)

Comment: Give it to @dobey, please. His answer is a lot better :)

Comment: Please feel free to also click the "Accept this answer" next to the answer. :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Create a chroot inside the home directory:

```
mkdir -p vivid-chroot
cd vivid-chroot
wget http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-touch/vivid/daily-preinstalled/current/vivid-preinstalled-touch-armhf.tar.gz
sudo tar -zxvf vivid-preinstalled-touch-armhf.tar.gz
```

Then, use the chroot and install whatever CLI tools you need to use, within that chroot:

```
cd ~/vivid-chroot
sudo chroot .
apt-get update
apt-get install git
```

In order to perform certain things, it may be required to bind mount some directories. You will need to take extra care when doing so, if you wish to delete the chroot from your phone, or perform other destructive actions.

```
sudo mount --bind /proc /home/phablet/vivid-chroot/proc
sudo mount --bind /dev /home/phablet/vivid-chroot/dev
sudo mount --bind /sys /home/phablet/vivid-chroot/sys
```

This isn't an exhaustive list, but you can bind mount other directories as needed in similar fashion. You need not create the chroot in your home directory if you have an external storage device to create it on, such as an SD card. However, not all phones have SD card slots. If you wish to create the chroot on an SD card, simply replace the home directory in the commands above, with the path to a directory on your alternate storage media where you wish to create the chroot.

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot for this guide! I'm glad that I don't have to mess with `/` anymore when I want to fiddle with my phone....

Comment: Also, `sudo mount -o bind /run /home/phablet/vivid-chroot/run` to get network inside chroot http://askubuntu.com/questions/469209/how-to-resolve-hostnames-in-chroot

Comment: @sdbbs I don't think that's necessary. I don't bind mount anything in my chroot, and network access works fine. I use bzr and apt all the time within it.

Comment: I copied /etc/resolv.conf into vivid-chroot/etc to get dns resolution working.

Comment: This guide worked for me alos. Though I also did have to copy the resolv.conf to make DNS work

Answer (score 4):

**Warning:** this is only an **hack** to get rid of the cross-device link problem on apt-get upgrade with powerd package. this is not a "UBUNTU" certified solution

Prerequisite: having made R/W the ubuntu installation with:

```
phablet-config writable-image
```

Copy the downloaded powerd*.deb file from the phone to a PC from the path:

/var/cache/apt/archives/

On the PC, unpack the .deb file, remove the file /usr/share/powerd/device_configs/config-default.xml (from my tests it results not foundamental):

```
su - root
mkdir tmp
dpkg-deb -R powerd_0.16+15.04.20150507-0ubuntu1_armhf.deb tmp
rm tmp/usr/share/powerd/device_configs/config-default.xml
mv powerd_0.16+15.04.20150507-0ubuntu1_armhf.deb old.deb
dpkg-deb -b tmp powerd_0.16+15.04.20150507-0ubuntu1_armhf.deb
```

Everything must be done as root to keep the original permissions of the package files and dirs.
Repack, copy back on the phone, then install with:

```
sudo dpkg -i powerd_0.16+15.04.20150507-0ubuntu1_armhf.deb
```

You will still get the error:

"/usr/share/powerd/device_configs/config-default.xml": Device or resource busy

But at the end the package is updated.

Now if you do:  `sudo  apt-get upgrade` the error disappeared.

My phone BQ Aquaris seems to work well and stable.

Comment: Thanks for the solution! Will not accept for now as I still hope to get a  more *recommended* (don't have to be *supported*) way to do so. BTW. what about future updates of `powerd`? does it require to hack it on every update?

Comment: Till someone will resolve this problem of using hardlinks in dpkg (an old story) on a cross device installation, at the moment I don't see  alternative solution.

Comment: May be that should be possible to change some mount points in rder to avoid this cross device hardlink, but need some time to be analized. Only by looking to  fstab file or mont output I was not able to figure out what to chance

Answer (score 3):

As has already been pointed out, you have to install an ARM-capable chroot on your device and install all the required packages in that chroot. However, doing so in your home directory wastes a lot of valuable space. Instead, it can be done on your SD-card using a computer running on an appropriate Linux OS (tested on Linux Mint 17 and Ubuntu Trusty). As I did not find any information about this anywhere else, I put it here as an answer to an old question.

The following instructions assume you want to install a debian jessie chroot in the directory jessie.

## Creating and populating the image file on a desktop computer

### Creating an empty image file

To create an 1GB image called IMAGE.img in the current working directory, do:

`dd if=/dev/zero of=IMAGE.img bs=1G count=1`

Note that the B in GB is left out. "if" stands for "input file", "of" for
"output file" and "bs" for "block size".

There are more efficient commands out there, but those only work on certain
types of file systems, as far as I know.  This one also works on an SD-card or
a tempfs.  Please note the use of /dev/zero and not /dev/random or /dev/urandom
as that would take a lot longer and make it take a lot longer to transfer the
image between devices later on.

### Creating a file system on the image

Without the file system, the phone would not be able to store any data on the
image. Without a file system, you cannot yet mount the image to a directory,
only to a block-device.

This bash-command will output the next empty loop device into the variable `LOOP`:

`$LOOP=$(sudo losetup -f)`

Next, assign the image to a block device:

`sudo losetup $LOOP IMAGE.img`

Next, create the ext4 file system on it:

`sudo mkfs -t ext4 $LOOP`

Next, detach the image from the loop device:

`sudo losetup -d $LOOP`

If you get command not found errors, just install the missing programmes.

### Mount the image file on the computer to access it

Now, create a temporary directory in the working directory:

`mkdir jessie`

and mount the image file IMAGE.img to it:

`sudo mount -o loop IMAGE.img $(pwd)/jessie`

The command `pwd` will make sure you give mount an absolute path to your
current working directory.

### Populating the image with the new operating system with qemu-debootstrap

The next step will be to use qemu-debootstrap to download the necessary files.
This is easy if qemu-debootstrap is available as is the case on Ubuntu and
derived OSes. If you get command not found errors when executing
`qemu-debootstrap --help`, try to install the appropriate package, which can be
done on Ubuntu via:

`sudo apt-get install qemu-user-static`

To download all required files and ready the new OS, run the following command:

`sudo qemu-debootstrap --arch=armhf jessie ./jessie http://http.debian.net/debian`

Please note that the first `jessie` stands for the OS version whereas the
second `jessie` stands for the directory where the files are to be installed.Now you can unmount the image as the rest of the work has to be done on the
phone. Do so via:

`sudo umount $(pwd)/jessie`

If you cannot install qemu-debootstrap, see the next section.

### Populating the image with the new operating system without qemu-debootstrap

Please skip this section if you have qemu-debootstrap available. You will still
need a native debootstrap for you architecture, though. If this happens to be
armhf, just use the above command line but replace `qemu-debootstrap` by
`debootstrap`. If not, follow this section.

To download all required files for the new OS, run the following command:

```
sudo debootstrap --arch=armhf --foreign jessie ./jessie \
    http://http.debian.net/debian
```

Now you can unmount the image as the rest of the work has to be done on the
phone. Do so via:

`sudo umount $(pwd)/jessie`

## Transfer image to the phone

Now best create a tar archive from this which you then copy to your
phone. It does not matter whether the archive is put on the SD-card or
the internal storage. Create the archive on the desktop using:

`tar -cvzf jessie.tar.gz IMAGE.img`

Now, on your phone, turn on ssh support to copy the image over. You might also
do that using a USB-cable instead. Since the ssh server is reset on every
reboot, start the ssh service on the phone via:
`sudo service ssh start`

Next, copy the image via:

`scp jessie.tar.gz phablet@ubuntu-phablet:$COPYDIR`

where the variable `COPYDIR` contains the directory where the image shall be
stored.  This command assumes that your username on the phone is phablet and
the phone's hostname is ubuntu-phablet. You can find out both by issuing `echo $USER`
and `echo $HOSTNAME` on the phone, respectively.

Now you only have to extract the archive wherever you want the image to reside. Assume the directory where you want the image to be located
is stored in the variable `IMAGEDIR`. Extract the image there via the bash
command:

`( cd $IMAGEDIR; tar -xvzf $COPYDIR/jessie.tar.gz; )`

You might now remove the archive:

`rm $COPYDIR/jessie.tar.gz`

## Finalizing and using the image on the phone

If you did not turn on the ssh server on the phone, do so now via:

`sudo service ssh start`

Next, mount your image to a directory of your choice (in this case "jessie"):

`sudo mount -o loop $IMAGEDIR/IMAGE.img $(pwd)/jessie`

Now, enter your chroot for the first time via:

`ssh localhost "sudo chroot $(pwd)/jessie /bin/bash"`

If you had qemu-debootstrap available on your computer, you're all done. Use
the above 2 commands to connect to your chroot. If not, you still have to
execute the following command once you are inside your chroot, in order to
properly setup the OS:

`/debootstrap/debootstrap --second-stage`

## Summary of how to access the chroot

If you followed the above steps, you should be able to access your chroot using
this simple script on the phone:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo service ssh start
ssh localhost "sudo chroot jessie /bin/bash"
```

You have to first ssh into your own phone from the phone due to apparmor restrictions of the terminal app. The terminal app is only allowed to execute binaries in certain locations and neither your home directory nor the SD card are among those. The ssh service, however, does not have such restrictions.

Answer (score 1):

## Make root filesystem on phone writable

To remount root filesystem as writable, execute the following command on your phone (download [terminal app](https://uappexplorer.com/app/com.ubuntu.terminal) if you haven't already):

```
sudo mount -o remount,rw /
```

Please note that **after rebooting your phone, `/` is read-only again**. If you want this to be permanent, change `/etc/fstab`. However, Ubuntu touch on the BQ is not on the main Ubuntu arm repo's yet. Installing things like `tree` or `libreoffice` won't work yet. They might be in the latest devel version.

## Running the latest devel version of Ubuntu

(has more goodies in the repo, like commandline tools and such)

[How to run latest Ubuntu touch development release on bq phone?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/603005/how-to-run-latest-ubuntu-touch-development-release-on-bq-phone)

## Fixing stuff when you break everything

When you break thing completely, you can [just reflash your device](https://askubuntu.com/a/602037/172367).