# Can you run Web Dev packages on aquaris m10

Tags: php, aquaris, web-development, m10

I'm very tempted to buy the new Aquaris M10 instead of a new laptop. Can you run packages like PHP Storm/xampp/git/php on there? Does it have a fully operational terminal? Would the processor be able to handle these type of packages without grinding to a halt?

Comment: I think you could have a look here and decide yourself http://www.ubuntu.com/tablet/devices

Comment: I've read that. I was asking more if anyone had actual experience of using it for these things as opposed to reading specs.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have a high enough reputation to add a comment, but I thought I would share in an aswer my current experience.

I am a web developer. I have been using ubuntu for many years and am comfortable with apt-get and a little configuration.

I bought my Aquaris M10 with the purpose of using it as a travel computer. The idea is that it would be handy to use for browsing and videos as a tablet but still enable me to develop with Ruby on Rails. So far it is frustrating me that it is not easier to set up basic dev tools.

The problem is that you can't use apt-get directly but have to do some chroot magic to install .deb packages to work with the ARM architecture.
[Recommended way to install regular(cli) .deb packages on Ubuntu Phone?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/620740/recommended-way-to-install-regularcli-deb-packages-on-ubuntu-phone)

My current plan is to wait for the ugrade to ubuntu 16.04 before attempting this as I gather things will be easier then.

Yes, terminal is functional but out of the box you are very limitted to which system files you can edit and the the overall experience I found is not highly responsive. I don't know if the responsiveness is a problem that can be fixed. `top` shows the load average is generally between 10 and 12. That would bring my desktop to its knees but perhaps ARM works differently.

It is thrilling to be using the first ubuntu tablet off the shelf. I would never have bought a non linux tablet. But if I could go back in time I would either have bought a netbook, which would have performed miles better for less money, or I would have held off until the next version. The tablet is working well as a touch device, no problems adding blue tooth keyboard and mouse, but I was expecting more from the desktop experience.

I am optimistic it will get there very soon. I love the concept of phone/tablet and computer in one.

Edit:

There is a useful help page for installing packages with Libertine here:
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Libertine

Comment: I completely answered your question, but I'll update my answer once I know and have tried more.

Comment: Perfect answer! Thank you for that and covered everything I wanted to know