# command line calendar (cal) on M10 tablet not working

Tags: ubuntu-touch, tablet, execute-command, m10

The command `cal` does not work on my M10 tablet, both in tablet and in desktop modes;  it is the only failure I have found so far.  Has anyone any ideas as to why it fails?  Are there any other commands that do not work on the M10?

Comment: What is CAL? Do you mean cal (command line calendar) ?

Comment: Yes, Bruni, I mean the command line calendar.  I am newly returned to Linux after many years, and still making many newbie errors!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command `cal` is not installed by default on Ubuntu Touch. Contrary to desktop Ubuntu you can not simply install it through `apt-get`.

Your options are:

1. wait for somebody to package it for Ubuntu Touch (unlikely, as this is not really a typical tablet/phone application)
2. mount your system r/w and install with `apt-get` (DON'T DO THIS, it will likely break your system)
3. install it in a container or chroot (but this is not trivial, see https://askubuntu.com/a/623311/532550 for full instructions)
4. install it from source in your home directory (if the necessary compilers etc. are available)
5. use a different application

I think your best options are 4 and 5.

P.S.: "does not work" and "fails" is not really a useful error description. To allow people to help you, include all necessary information, in this case the command you ran and the error message you got:

```
phablet@ubuntu-phablet:~$ cal
bash: cal: command not found
```

Comment: That is a very full and helpful answer.  It also explains why the Ubuntu Touch version differs from the desktop one.  I am grateful for your trouble.

Comment: I'm glad this was helpful. If you think this answers your question feel free to mark the answer as "accepted".