# How do I root an Ubuntu Touch device?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, root, phone

How can I have a shell with root in the most straightforward way with an Ubuntu Touch?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no "rooting" an Ubuntu phone in the same way you do on Android. You already have root. You can install the terminal app and can use *sudo* to run things as root if necessary.

However, you should not really mess about with the root filesystem partition being read-only. If you need to install CLI tools, it's best done inside an existing Libertine container, or by creating a chroot, as per the instructions in [Recommended way to install regular(cli) .deb packages on Ubuntu phone?](https://askubuntu.com/a/623311/50737)