# Installing packages on Nexus 4

Tags: upgrade, ubuntu-touch, repository, nexus-4

the repos for ubuntu touch are shut down by now, but I would like to install packages on my nexus 4. The current version is 15.04 with no update to a newer version available. Do you hava any ideas which repos I could try to use?

Comment: UT is no longer developed.

Comment: yeah right. I just want to use the old version, but I can't install packages from the old repos because they are switched off. Is there an equivalent to old-releases.ubuntu.com for the ports repos?

Comment: You should switch to the ubports builds. See https://ubports.com/ (And for everyone else, I think questions about Ubports are on topic, as it's a sanctioned continuation of the project).

Comment: Also see https://askubuntu.com/a/623311/50737 for how to create a chroot for installing CLI deb packages if that is what you want. You can simply grab the 16.04 xenial pre-installed tarball instead of vivid, and you'll have an LTS chroot.

Comment: @dobey: that's not a comment... That's an answer! (ping me here and I'll come back to upvote)

Comment: @seifar old-releases is where the ports are. The UBports 15.04 images are updated to pull from there, also for libertine. There are also in-progress devel 16.04 images. Depending on what your doing, that may be a better option, perhaps also with a chroot.

Comment: @Fabby It's a bit unclear on what exactly the question is supposed to be here, so I don't feel comfortable posting any answer here yet, until I really understand what is being asked.

Answer (score 1):

You should definitely switch your device over to the UBports version of Ubuntu Touch. Even though now updates are published for the 15.04 packages, some important security patches were backported, and all the package sources are changed to old-releases.ubuntu.com in OTA-3, so you can still install packages. A new version of Ubuntu Touch based on 16.04 is also in development and the Nexus 4 will be supported.

To switch to UBports' version of the Operating System, use the [UBports Installer](https://github.com/ubports/ubports-installer). Select the 15.04/stable channel and make sure not to tick the "Wipe" box to keep the data in your home folder. Your root-filesystem will be reset though, so any deb packages you installed before you will have to install again. In the future, you might want to use [OTR](https://open.uappexplorer.com/app/ontheroad.emanuelesorce).