# Ubuntu Touch apt error The repository does not have a Release file

Tags: 16.04, apt, ubuntu-touch

I installed Ubuntu Touch to a Nexus 5 phone and I can't install any program with apt-get. Can you help me?

```
phablet@ubuntu-phablet:/etc/apt$ uname -a
Linux ubuntu-phablet 3.4.0-cyanogenmod-g2669fa0 #1 SMP PREEMPT Fri Aug 24 02:24:01 CEST 2018 armv7l armv7l armv7l GNU/Linux
phablet@ubuntu-phablet:/etc/apt$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list
## EOL upgrade sources.list
# Required
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-security main restricted universe multiverse


phablet@ubuntu-phablet:/etc/apt$ sudo apt clean && sudo apt update
Hit:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/mc3man/xerus-media/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Ign:2 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease                                                                    
Ign:3 http://repo.ubports.com xenial InRelease                                                                                  
Hit:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/phablet-team/tools/ubuntu xenial InRelease                                                       
Ign:5 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease                           
Hit:6 http://repo.ubports.com xenial Release                             
Ign:7 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease    
Err:8 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.41 80]
Err:9 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.41 80]
Err:10 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.41 80]
Reading package lists... Done                      
E: The repository 'http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Comment: Xenial which refers to 16.04 is still supported as LTS, i.e. no need to use old-releases.ubuntu.com. Just use a standard mirror, like http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The supported method of installing applications on Ubuntu Touch is via click packages from the [Open Store](https://open-store.io), and installing via `apt` is not supported.

Ubuntu 16.04 is also not EOL, so would not be on old-releases host.

If you want to use apt to install development tools or such, the supported ways to do this are with *Libertine* or with a traditional chroot as described [in my answer here](https://askubuntu.com/a/623311/50737).